# Given a group of people with timings for 2 events, find the shortest total time for X and Y given that events are mutually exclusive

Tags: optimization

Your classmates elected you to be in charge of the creation of the short and long distance running teams for the upcoming Sports Day event in your school. They have kindly given you their timings for both the short and long distance relay. Classes are will be ranked based on the shortest total time of both events combined.

The event mandates that you must have S short distance and L long distance runners, and participants can only take part in one event; if they are already taking part in the short distance relay, they cannot take part in the long distance one.

Find the shortest total time of both events in `O(n log n)` time.

Failed approaches I've explored:

- Greedy with 2 heaps -- does not work as the local optimal does not result to a global optimal

  - counterexample: it might be better to "sacrifice" an `s` because the next best `l` is significantly slower
- Sort the array based on the difference between `s-l` of each classmate so that the array is  sorted by those who are better at short distance in one end and long distance at another, but I was not sure how to proceed from here. Thought about using the 2 ends to be S and L but this does not necessarily guarantee the shortest total time.

  - counterexample: the sorting only ensures that the ends of the array are the best `s` and `l` if they were to be chosen, there may exist another athlete with better absolute times for the respective events

source: supposedly easier version of https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/730/I

Comment: Can you elaborate on specifically what greedy strategies you have considered, and give a counterexample for each, so that others don't have to repeat your attempt?

Comment: @D.W. I have update them accordingly.